# Octopus Release Version Readonly

Tags: release, continuous-deployment, octopus-deploy

I am using the tool octopus deploy for the CD process. I have a problem, during the release, some members of the team edited the release number manually and deployed So the sequence of the release number has inconsistency.

For example

- 1.1.9096
- 1.1.9097.1
- 1.1.9098

I am wondering is there any way to validate the release ? or is it possible to make version number read-only?

[image: octopus release]

Answer (score 3):

In Octopus, anyone with the ability to create a release can also select the release number at creation time. You can see more about available standard roles and how to customize them in the [Octopus documentation here](https://octopus.com/docs/security/users-and-teams#Managingusersandteams-Roles).

There are two recommended approaches:

1. Set up your [release versioning](https://octopus.com/docs/releases/release-versioning) to automatically increment - for example, the bottom figure on the documentation page shows the variable setup to get a `YEAR.MONTH.DAY.REVISION` release number (e.g the first release of the day is versioned `2022.4.26.0`, the next is  `2022.4.26.1`, and so on). With this set as your versioning strategy, you can create a release without a version number specified and it will auto increment the version without intervention.
2. If you're creating a release as a part of your build process in your CI tool, you can likely use the [build server plugin](https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/build-servers) for Octopus Deploy to manage the release numbers (for example, it's common to create a release that matches the build number in the CI system to make it easier to identify the matching builds/releases)